# Windows shutdowns instead of going to sleep

Tags: windows, sleep, power

about a week ago i updated my Windows 10 to build 1909 and after that my sleep functionality is broken and it shutdowns every time i set it to sleep.
i already tried downgrading Intel MEL to v9 and nothing has changed
Any idea?

```
Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 1909
Os Build 18363.592
```

I found a Critical level page even in my event viewer:
The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

```
    - <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" /> 
  <EventID>41</EventID> 
  <Version>6</Version> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <Task>63</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000400000000002</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-01-29T10:06:07.291271800Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>49752</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-***</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="SleepInProgress">4</Data> 
  <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BootAppStatus">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="Checkpoint">16</Data> 
  <Data Name="ConnectedStandbyInProgress">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="SystemSleepTransitionsToOn">1</Data> 
  <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceId">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckInfoFromEFI">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="CheckpointStatus">0</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

PS:none of Similar question and answers solved my issue.

Comment: what troubleshooting actions have you taken so far?

Comment: downgrading MEI,windows troubleshoot,sfc

Comment: Update your BIOS, Chipset Driver, Power Driver and all other drivers using the Manufacturer's update app.  Restart when requested (after BIOS for example) and do a final restart and test

Comment: @John Thanks,but according to Asus Live update and Intel DSA all my drivers are in their latest version and also I double checked with Asus support and reinstalled them all but still same situation.

Comment: If all the drivers are up to date, do a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation (start with Keep Everything): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Try: (1) *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Power > Run the troubleshooter*, (2) Try to rollback the Intel Rapid Storage Technology Driver in *Device Manager > Storage Controllers* right-click "Intel® Chipset SATA/PCIe RST Premium Controller", select Properties, Driver tab. Create at least a System Restore point before starting.

Comment: @harrymc Well,troubleshooter didn't work as i mentioned before, and I don't have Intel RST listed in my device manager also when I tried to install ,it said "this platform is not supported"

Comment: What is your computer?